# Отправка данных из формы в бд

Tags: php, mysql

Уже задавал ранее, но так и не разобрался.
1. Есть HTML-страница, на которой есть форма и кнопка "отправить". В данный момент кнопка отправить передаёт данные на mail.php и письмо отправляется на email.
2. Есть php-файл, в котором есть всё нужное для записи данных из формы в БД.
Вот фрагмент html формы (укоротил, там и так всё понятно).

```
<form method="POST" action="mysql.php" class="callback form-order">
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label>
                                    <p>Имя:</p>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" required>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label>
                                    <p>Фамилия:</p>
                                    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Фамилия" required>
                                </label>
                            </div>
<div class="text-center">
                            <button  class="button">Отправить</button>
                        </div>
```

Вот файл mail.php. В нём всё работает, письма уходят исправно.

```
 <?php


    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];


    //Script Foreach
    $c = true;
    if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

        $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
        $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
        $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

        foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
                $message .= "
                " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
    } else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

        $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
        $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
        $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

        foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
                $message .= "
                " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
    }

    $message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

    function adopt($text) {
        return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
    }

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
    'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
    'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;


       mail($admin_email, ado

    pt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
    ?>
```

И вот файл mysql.php

```
    <?php


//Параметры подключения в БД
$host = "11"; //имя хоста
$database = "11"; //имя базы
$user = "11"; //пользователь
$password = "11"; //пароль
$dbtable = "Users"; //таблица

if (isset($_POST['name'])){
//переменные с формы
$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
$surname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['surname'];
$secondname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['secondname'];
$phone = strip_tags(trim($_POST['phone'];
$birthdate = strip_tags(trim($_POST['birthdate'];
$birhtplace = strip_tags(trim($_POST['birhtplace'];
$citizenship = strip_tags(trim($_POST['citizenship'];
$doc = strip_tags(trim($_POST['doc'];
$docid = strip_tags(trim($_POST['docid'];
$docpublish = strip_tags(trim($_POST['docpublish'];
$docdate = strip_tags(trim($_POST['docdate'];
$regterm = strip_tags(trim($_POST['regterm'];
$comment = strip_tags(trim($_POST['comment'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("H:i:s")

//установим соединение с бд
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$dbtable." (order_date, order_time, name, surname, second_name, phone, birth_date, birht_place, citizenship, doc, doc_id, doc_publish, doc_date, term) VALUES ('$date', '$time', '$name', '$surname', '$secondname', '$phone', '$birthdate', '$birhtplace', '$citizenship', '$doc', '$docid', '$docpublish', '$docdate', '$regterm', '$comment')"

//внесём данные с формы в БД
$res = mysqli_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error()." in ". $sql);

mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как мне корректно передать данные из формы в БД через этот файл mysql.php чтобы одновременно ещё и письмо ушло через mail.php ?
Не тыкайте меня, пожалуйста, а объясните подробно, что именно я делаю не так.

Добавляю скрипты js.

```
<script>
 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
 function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
 gtag('js', new Date());

 gtag('config', 'UA-135456404-1');
</script>


<script>
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
var callback = function () {
if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
window.location = url;
}
};
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
'send_to': 'AW-760147299/6bfxCOvJm5YBEOPau-oC',
'transaction_id': '',
'event_callback': callback
});
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ну, по идее можно в `mysql.php` сверху просто подключить `include 'mail.php';`

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов объясните, пожалуйста, что это даст? 
Попробовал - бесполезно.

Comment: `include` просто включает код из другого файла в текущий. У вас, по идее, 2 пути решения: Вы можете либо скопировать код отправки на почту в ваш `mysql.php` (то есть объединить 2 задачи в один файл), либо подключить код отправки почты с помощью `include` или `require`

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов попробовал и то и другое - результатов ноль.

Comment: Подскажите, я правильно понял: форма у вас одна. Когда Вы в `action` формы ставите `mail.php` или `mysql.php`, по отдельности работают они?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов да, форма одна. Изначально в action вообще ничего не стояло, я добавил только mysql.php. 
Подключал отправку почты фрилансер и каким-то непонятным мне способом, скорее всего обработчиком нажатия кнопки

Comment: Возможно, этот обработчик вообще не дает форме отправляться. Попробуйте из 'mysql.php' убрать все и написать что-то простое, вроде `<?php echo 'Текст из mysql.php';`, чтобы проверить, доходит ли вообще отправка формы до `mysql.php`. В вообще, конечно, надо бы js посмотреть, так все это бестолку.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов добавил в вопрос два скрипта. Есть ещё файл для jQuery стандартный.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Были синтаксические ошибки в php.
Запрос к MySQL был составлен неверно, количество полей должно быть равно количеству values и столбцов за исключение id (автоинкремент).